# Setting feepayer of versionedTransaction

Tags: fees, versionedtransactions, priority-fees, jupiter

I'm using the jupiter swap api (https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api) to perform token swaps and they return a versionedTransaction object which I hope to set the fee payer to a specific wallet.

I know that I can set the feepayer of the legacy transaction object, but I don't see a similar field for the new versionedTransaction object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TransactionMessage.decompile` on the `VersionedTransaction`'s inner `VersionedMessage` to get back everything https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/message.ts#L35

This would look roughly like:

```
const versionedTx = // get it from API
const decompiledMessage = TransactionMessage.decompile(versionedTx.message);
decompiledMessage.feePayer = // whatever you want
const newVersionedTx = new VersionedTransaction(decompiledMessage.compileToV0Message());
// sign your new transaction with all signers
```

Note that this isn't perfect and might not work -- if there are any signatures in the provided transaction, they will be lost and invalid if you modify the underlying message. This holds for legacy and v0 transactions.